# jQuery selecting element inside a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have something like this :

```
 var _tiles = $('.tile');
```

Now I want to select the `.active tiles`, how can I do so if I want to use the variable instead of doing something like this :

```
 $('.tile.active');
```

To avoid the DOM parsing again...

Comment: Your code can't work because $'('.tile') is an incorrect jquery selector.

Comment: Make your question specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var activeTiles = _tiles.filter('.active');
```

Because you've already cached your elements in `_tiles`, no further DOM lookup is necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I should have RTFM but I'll remember now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can search with a selector inside a variable like this:

```
var activeTile = $('.active', _tiles);
```

Comment: Nice. I would have done a .each() with .hasClass()...

Comment: An interesting solution. I wonder which is faster - `.filter()` or this method `:)`

Comment: @Bojangles: It doesn't matter because they do different things. (`.find` vs `.filter`). The performance test you added to your answer is irrelevant.

Comment: .find() is to look through the child nodes. I wantes to stay on the same node

Comment: @Felix Ah yes of course - `_tiles` is a _collection_ of elements isn't it. I've removed the JSPerf test

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.find function](http://api.jquery.com/find/) _tiles.find(".active")